# javascript image load works only one time

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my code I load an image:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src= 'image.png';
```

And then I append this image to a div like this:

```
$('#divname').append(img);
```

So far everything works fine, but when I try to append the same image to another div, for example:

```
$('#divname2').append(img);
```

The image no longer exists. What I mean is when I open the page the first `div` contains the image but the second `div` does not. Respectively if I change the order of `appends` the `#divname2` will contain the image. Is this a normal javascript behavior or am I doing something wrong? Is it possible to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Is this a normal javascript behavior or am I doing something wrong?

Yes, it is normal. When using `append`, or other method that add a node on the page, with an already existing element, it only move the passed element.

## Is it possible to fix this issue?

The native solution is to use [`cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode) :

```
$('#divname2').append(img.cloneNode());
```

Other alternative would be to pass the outerHTML to `append` :

```
$('#divname2').append(img.outerHTML);
```

Comment: I tried the `cloneNode()` and it works. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to clone the element like this :

```
$('#divname2').append($(img).clone());
```

An other solution would be to append html directly.

```
var img = '<img src="image.png" />';
$('#divname').append(img);
$('#divname2').append(img);
```

Comment: img is not a jQuery object ;) (well not yet)

Comment: Thx my bad. The solution is still good, you have to clone the element.

Answer (score 1):

When you append the element via `$('#divname2').append(img)`, the original element is removed from it's parent since `img` is a reference to it. Append a [clone](http://api.jquey.com/clone) of the image instead:

```
var $img = $("<img/>", {
  src: 'image.png'
});
$('#divname').append($img);
$('#divname2').append($img.clone());
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery .append() method moves the element. You want to clone the element.

One method:

```
$('#divname').append(img);
$('#divname2').append($(img).clone());
```